# Preenchendo div com informação de um forms

Tags: javascript, php

Pessoal estou tentando fazer aparecer um valor em uma div com o resultado de um form sem refresh, porém preciso fazer isso para vários registros que vem direto do php;

Estou usando o código abaixo, porém me retorna o mesmo resultado, necessito de várias divs para cada valor de formulario, ou seja imagino que o jscript tem que me gerar varias divs diferentes....

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.input').keyup(function() {
    $('div.showDiv').html($(this).val());
  })
})
```

```css
input,div {
padding: 6px;
display:block
}
```

```html
<input class='input' type='text'>
<div class='showDiv'></div>
```

Comment: A pergunta está confusa, mas seria isso o quer fazer `$('.showDiv').append($(.input).val());` ?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar uma relação entre href e class para preencher os dados no div.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let $inputs = $('input.input');

    $('input.input').each(function(){
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            $('div.'+$(this).attr('href')).html($(this).val());
        })

    })

})
```

```css
input, div {
    padding: 6px;
    display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='input' type='text' href="div1">
<div class='div1'></div>
<input class='input' type='text' href="div2">
<div class='div2'></div>
<input class='input' type='text' href="div3">
<div class='div3'></div>
<input class='input' type='text' href="div4">
<div class='div4'></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo ! Obrigado ! Agora uma segunda dúvida, como faço uma operação com este resultado do forms, por exemplo o valor do forms * uma variavel de preço ... exemplo valor digitado*40, dai o resultado seria essa operação ....